# Regex to match up to the last occurrence of a character if followed by alphanumerics, otherwise - match everything

Tags: regex

Given the following strings:

```
ab_cd
ef_gh_ij
kl_mn_op_qr
st_uv_1w2x
yz_ab_cd_e1f2
```

I want to match each substring up to (not including) the last occurrence of `_` if followed by alphanumerics (i.e. a sequence of **both** letters and numbers), otherwise - match everything.

Expected matches:

```
ab_cd
ef_gh_ij
kl_mn_op_qr
st_uv
yz_ab_cd
```

I currently have this non-working regex ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCCWJy/1)):

`^.*(?=_)[a-zA-z]+`

but for the alphanumerics ones - it matches the underscore itself plus one following character.

How to accomplish it?

Comment: What programming language are you using and must it be a single regex? If you have a function with each string as input, then you wouldn't necessarily need a regex, do you?

Comment: @knittl, (1) both JS and C# (2) need a regex because I think it would be less involved then a "parsing" code (i.e. splitting on `_`, checking if the last substring is alphanumeric, etc).

Comment: I think a "parser" is a lot less involved and lot more maintainable than a regex (which is already difficult to write).

Comment: Is it possible that some of the earlier substrings also have digits in them e.g. `yz_ab_e1f2_lw2x`? If so, what is your expected output?

Comment: @Nick, no. Assume numbers can only appear after the last underscore.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I had noticed some of the answers would not have worked in that scenario.

Comment: @OfirD What should be the match for `yz_ab_cd_2`  and for `yz_ab_e1f2_lw2x`

Comment: @Thefourthbird good one. `yz_ab_cd_2` doesn't end with alphanumerics (just numerics), so the whole string should be matched. `yz_ab_e1f2_lw2x` does have alphanumerics after the last underscore, so `yz_ab_e1f2` should be matched. I tested the accepted answer and it doesn't work for these cases, so you can suggest another answer if you will.

Comment: @OfirD Like this perhaps? `^\w+?(?=(?:_(?=\d*[a-z])[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*)?$)`  https://regex101.com/r/S4Hth2/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird yup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there must be both an alpha and a numeric char after the last underscore, and if not then match the whole string, you could use a case insensitive match:

```
^\w+?(?=(?:_(?=\d*[a-z])[a-z]*\d[a-z\d]*)?$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `\w+?` match 1+ word chars non greedy (or `.*?`)
- `(?=` Positive lookahead

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `_` Match literally
    - `(?=\d*[a-z])` Positive lookahead, assert a char a-z after optional digits
    - `[a-z]*\d` Match optional chars a-z and match a digit
    - `[a-z\d]*` Match optional chars a-z or digits
  - `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
  - `$` Assert end of string
- `)` Close the lookahead

Note that `.*?` optionally matches any character, and could also match an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A1xCwa/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use a running negative look ahead for underscore then digit in the next term:

```
^((?!_[^_]*\d).)*
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/F2qRa5QO12DVWe).

Comment: Last line should only match until `_`, not the full line

Comment: @knittl Thank you. I didn't notice that. Fixed.

Comment: Doesn't match a full `yz_ab_cd_123`, but only the part without digits. But it should be matched, if I understood the requirements correctly: "a sequence of **both** letters and numbers, otherwise match everything"

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that a non-regex (rather "enough-regex") solution is a lot simpler to: write, understand, extend, and maintain.

```
function match(input) {
  if (!input) return input;
  const parts = input.split('_');
  const last = parts[parts.length - 1];
  return /\w/.test(last) && /\d/.test(last)
    ? parts.slice(0, -1).join('_')
    : input;
}
```

Test code:

```
for (let input of inputs) console.log(`Matching ${input} matches ${match(input)}`);
```

and output:

```
Matching ab_cd matches ab_cd
Matching ef_gh_ij matches ef_gh_ij
Matching kl_mn_op_qr matches kl_mn_op_qr
Matching st_uv_1w2x matches st_uv
Matching yz_ab_cd_e1f2 matches yz_ab_cd
```

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

The following works the same in both ECMAScript and .NET:

```
^.*                # Match anything, as many as possible,
(?=_[^\W_]+$)      # up until we see the last '_'
                   # followed by a sequence of alphanumerics,
(?=.*\d)           # which contains at least one digit
(?=.*[A-Za-z])     # and one letter.
|                  # If we can't find such a match,
^.*                # fallback to anything.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wSd2e8/2).

### Original answer

```
^.*                # Match anything, as many as possible,
(?=                # up until
  _                # a '_',
  (?=[A-Za-z]*\d)  # after which is a sequence consisting of at least 1 digit
  (?=\d*[A-Za-z])  # and 1 letter, on the condition that
  [^\W_]+$         # this sequence consists of alphanumerics only.
)                  # If we can't find such a match,
|                  # fallback to
^.*                # anything.
```

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wSd2e8/1).

<s>I have a feeling that this might not be the best solution, but here it is anyway.</s> Found a better one.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/^[a-z_]+(?=$|_)/`

```
^        since start
[a-z_]+  match letters and underscore
(?=$|_)  followed by end of string or underscore
```